# ninja -C out/Release-x64 skia modules errors, "" needed by "", missing

Tags: clang, ninja, skia

I am trying to install skia on my Ubuntu 22.04 lts machine, so I can use aseprite. I've done the steps listed [here](https://github.com/aseprite/skia?tab=readme-ov-file#skia-on-linux) but I get this error:

```
$: ninja -C out/Release-x64 skia modules
ninja: Entering directory `out/Release-x64'
ninja: error: '../../third_party/externals/freetype/src/autofit/autofit.c', needed by 'obj/third_party/externals/freetype/src/autofit/libfreetype2.autofit.o', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Here is my clang version: `Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1` and cmake `cmake version 3.28.2`

Answer (score 0):

you probably didn't run `python tools/git-sync-deps` to pull dependencies mentioned in the first step.

`git-sync-deps` clones the third party dependencies to `third_party/externals` directory. ninja is complaining that it cannot find the freetype sources in that directory.